# Integrated battery charger for simulation in proteus 8

Tags: batteries, integrated-circuit, simulation, charger, proteus

I am looking for a library that has an integrated that has the battery charger functionality (MCP73831, MCP73833) to simulate it in proteus 8.

Supposedly there is a library for proteus of this integrated, but I have not found it to download, does anyone know where I could find it?

[image]
[image]

It doesn't necessarily have to be that integrated, do you know any other battery charger that I could use to simulate?